# Suppose $p, q$ ∈ N are prime numbers so that $x^3 −px+q$ has only integer roots. Solve for p and q

Tags: prime-numbers, roots, integers

I've got no idea how to do this question. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint:  If it has three integer roots then it can be written as $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ for $a,b,c\in \mathbb Z$, possibly not distinct.

Comment: It is not difficult to show that if $p$ and $q$ are positive integers such that the polynomial $x^3-px+q$ has three integer roots, then there exist positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $p=a^2+ab+b^2$ and $q=ab(a+b)$, in which case the roots of $x^3-px+q$ are $a$, $b$, and $-a-b$.

Answer (score 2):

By Vieta's formulae:
$$x_1x_2x_3=-q$$
Where $q$ is prime, $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb Z$

Let $x_1x_2=-1$ and $x_3=q$ or $x_1x_2=1$ and $x_3=-q$
We obtain: $$x_1=-1,x_2=1,x_3=q$$ or
$$x_1=1,x_2=1,x_3=-q$$

Then, for $x=1$:
$$1-p+q=0\;\land\; p\;\text{is prime}\implies p=q+1=2+1=3$$
Because there are only 2 consecutive prime numbers: $2, 3$

---

Edit:

as written above, one root definitely equals $1$, so:
$(x-1)\mid x^3-3x+2$

Long division:
$$(x^3-3x+2):(x-1)=x^2+x-2=x^2-x+2=(x-1)(x+2)\implies x^3-3x+2=(x-1)^2(x+2)$$
and we see the roots are our $2^{\text{nd}}$ option.

Comment: How dis you exclude the case $x_1=x_2=-1,x_3=q$?

Answer (score 1):

If $q$ is a root, so $$q^3-pq+q=0,$$ which gives $$q^2+1=p,$$ which is possible for $q=2$ and $p=5$ only.

Thus, $$x^3-5x+2=0$$ or
$$x^3-2x^2+2x^2-4x-x+2=0$$ or
$$4(x-2)(x^2+2x-1)=0,$$ which is a contradiction.

If $-q$ is a root, we obtain $$-q^3+pq+q=0,$$ which gives $$p=q^2-1,$$ which is possible for $q=2$ and $p=3$ only,  which gives $$x^3-3x+2=0$$ or
$$(x-1)^2(x+2)=0,$$ which is valid.

We have no another cases.